# Control Heroku worker with web request

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I have a trading bot that runs 24x7 to find good trade points. I am hosting that bot as a worker on Heroku.

There are some cases where i need to change the bot configurations in runtime. Currently I created a flask server which runs and whenever it gets the request, it forwards it to the bot and change the bot configs.

The thing is flask server is only up for 20 mins and then Heroku forcefully shuts it down, so the bot is also shuts down. Is there a way that i can run the worker and web simultaneously and still able to send the request from flask to bot?

Comment: the heroku free plan force your process to Sleeps after 30 mins of inactivity, so you need to create recurrent dummy activity to keep it alive

Comment: Thanks, that's what currently i was doing, but i needed perfect solution as i was about to deploy with service bus instead of REST

Comment: how many app running in your heroku? and which plan you're using (free/hobby/paid)?

Comment: There is only one worker process running and i am using free plan, I want a flask web process or something like that from which i can send REST requests

Comment: so you need a new flask app that send a REst request to your main app every one hour.

Comment: Indeed, but main app is a worker process and i don't know how can i communicate the worker with REST